# OMNeT++ - Veins - Create a scenario of 2 vehicules with a starting position defined

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm working on Veins | OMNeT++ | SUMO.
Is it possible to select the starting position of our cars and the destination? 
I only see spawn of vehicules at the exact same position and don't know how to adapt them. I've already read some topics explaining that we have cars that are created automatically by the TraCI module, but how can we control it?

Answer (score 0):

Cars are initially created by SuMO and then inserted in Veins by the *TraCIScenarioManager*. In the demo example from Veins, multiple vehicles are driving from the same origin to the same destination:

> 194 Cars leaving the Computer Science Building and campus of the University of Erlangen-Nuremberg

In order to have different traffic, you have to adjust the network description files of SuMO - in particular the `*.rou.xml`. See the [SuMO wiki](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes) for how to configure vehicles and routes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can following method in TraCICommandInterface.h.

```
bool addVehicle(std::string vehicleId, std::string vehicleTypeId, std::string routeId, simtime_t emitTime_st = -DEPART_NOW, double emitPosition = -DEPART_POS_BASE, double emitSpeed = -DEPART_SPEED_MAX, int8_t emitLane = -DEPART_LANE_BEST_FREE);
```